# Linking C++ .o files during run-time

Tags: c++

I've recently started trying to compile/link C++ code dynamically. Let's suppose I have an application MyApp.exe running. I want that program to load some compiled object files (.o) and do all the linking stuff. Is it possible or I need a shared library?

Comment: what would the point of this be? You couldn't produce your .exe unless the .o files were present during the linking phase, meaning there's no point in trying to link them later - they were linked when the .exe was built.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve.. do you want to load shared libraries during runtime, for something like a plugin system?

Comment: Yes, a plugin system. I don't want to use scripts because I fear they might be slow. I also thought there was another way than a shared library to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible

Yes.

> or I need a shared library?

That's exactly what a shared library *is*!

#### Update

For a plugin system you should look into the system API functions

- `LoadLibrary` `GetProcAddress` (Windows)
- `dlopen` `dlsym` (Linux, *BSD, MacOS)

The recommended approach for implementing a plugin is to have exactly one function of a specific name, common to all plugin modules, exported by the plugin.

This function serves two purposes:

1. initializing the plugin
2. filling a structure of function pointers with the pointers to the plugin's functions

That way the user of the plugin gets all the plugin's symbols by only a handful of system function calls, instead of littering the code with countless calls to `dlsym` or `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: This could use some expansion. Shared libraries are not *literally* object files. At least on Windows, you cannot `LoadLibrary` a `.obj` file - you must link your object(s) into a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

It is theoretically possible, but probably not practical. On Windows, you cannot dynamically load object (`.obj`) files using `LoadLibrary`, so you would have link the object(s) into a DLL first. This would require a linker (along with static library dependencies, etc.) compatible with the compiler used to produce the object files, knowledge of the appropriate linker flags for the objects, etc.

Generally, it makes more sense to produce needed DLLs as part of the same build process that is performing the compilation. That process is in a better position to have all the necessary tools and information.